# What is the rational rank of the elliptic curve x^3 + y^3 = 2?

Tags: nt.number-theory

In Unsolved Problems in Number Theory, 3rd edition, section D1, 2004, R. K. Guy says, "Andrew Bremner has computed the rational rank of the elliptic curve x^3 + y^3 = Taxicab(n) as equal to 2, 4, 5, 4 for n = 2, 3, 4, 5, respectively." Since Taxicab(1) = 2, my question can be restated:

What is the rational rank of the elliptic curve x^3 + y^3 = Taxicab(1)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's isomorphic to $y^2 = x^3 - 27$, which has rank $0$.

Comment: How do you show those two claims, or what is a reference? Thanks.

Comment: In particular, why is (1,1) a torsion point on x^3 + y^3 = 2 (as your answer implies)?

Comment: Since it has a rational point, it's isomorphic to its Jacobian (for which there are classical formulas - for instance see http://math.arizona.edu/~wmc/Research/JacobianFinal.pdf) which has the equation I wrote. Then mwrank (which you can call in sage, for instance) tells you it has rank $0$. You can also see that $(1,1)$ is a torsion point by seeing that the line $x + y = 2$ which is tangent to the cubic at $(1,1)$ has as the third point of intersection the point at infinity $(1:-1:0)$ (which you can take to be the origin of the elliptic curve).

Comment: Thanks. I cited your answer at https://oeis.org/A230564.

Answer (score 16):

To add to Abhinav's answer: the fact that $x^3+y^3=2$ has no solutions
other then $x=y=1$ is attributed by Dickson to Euler himself:
see Dickson's *History of the Theory of Numbers*  (1920) Vol.II, Chapter XXI
"Numbers the Sum of Two Rational Cubes", page 572.  The reference
(footnote 182) is
"Algebra, 2, 170, Art. 247; French transl., 2, 1774, pp. 355–60;
Opera Omnia, (1), I, 491".  In the next page Dickson also refers to
work of Legendre that includes this result (footnote 184: "Théorie
des nombres, Paris, 1798, 409; ...").

This result is actually easier than the $n=3$ case of Fermat,
because the curve has a $2$-torsion point, so only a $2$-descent
is required, and here one soon finds that there are only two
rational points (the second being the point at infinity
$(x:y:1) = (1:-1:0)$).  [It also happens that this curve has
conductor $36$, while it's known that the smallest conductor
of an elliptic curve of positive rank is $37$; but that's
using a huge modern cannon to dispatch a classical fly.]

An easy way to bring the curve $x^3+y^3=2$ into Weierstrass form
is to factor $x^3+y^3 = (x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)$ and substitute
$(x,y)=(r+s,r-s)$ to get $r^3+3rs^2=1$.  Thus $s^2=(1-r^3)/(3r)$,
so $3r(1-r^3)$ is to be a square.  Now substitute $r=3/X$ to get
$s^2 = (X^3-27)/(3X)^2$, or equivalently $Y^2=X^3-27$ where $y=3sX$.
The solution $(x,y)=(1,1)$ corresponds to $(r,s)=(1,0)$ and then
$(X,Y)=(3,0)$, which we recognize as a 2-torsion point because $Y=0$.

Comment: Thanks. I cited your comment at https://oeis.org/A230564.